# kdb: can the $ function take 5 arguments?

Tags: kdb

From https://code.kx.com/q/wp/parse-trees/#the-solution

I came across below function, which translates enlisted symbols or symbol lists into the string "enlist".

```
ereptest:{ //returns a boolean
  (1=count x) and ((0=type x) and 11=type first x) or 11=type x}
ereplace:{"enlist",.Q.s1 first x}
funcEn:{$[ereptest x;ereplace x;0=type x;.z.s each x;x]}  <<<<<
```

In last line, it seems `$` is applied to 5 arguments, but [this page](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/overloads/#dollar) shows `$` is of rank 2 or 3. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [kx wiki](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cond/)

> **Odd number of expressions**
>
> For brevity, nested triads can be flattened.
>
> ```
> $[q;a;r;b;c] <=> $[q;a;$[r;b;c]]
> ```
>
> These two expressions are equivalent:
>
> ```
> $[0;a;r;b;c]
>     $[r;b;c]
> ```